# Fullscreen и разметка. Аномалия

Tags: java, android, разметка, экран

Уже не знаю куда и что копать.
В манифесте у меня указана тема

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"
```

В стилях она обозначена так:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@color/white</item>
```

Сделано Activity с контейнером для фрагментов. В манифесте оно обозначено

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity_032021"
    android:exported="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
```

Есть фрагмент настройки основного экрана приложения, и при указанных выше настройках Его разметка не сжимается при появлении клавиатуры
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Над клавиатурой должен быть кружок со стрелкой. Разметка этого фрагмента androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout, пробовал ещё RelativeLayout.

Это полбеды. Если я уберу из стиля строки

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

То разметка на этом фрагменте и на других, при появлении клавиатуры не слетает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при этом, если я нажму клавиши изменения уровня звука, то у меня вылетает статус-бар... И приложение уже не занимает полный экран

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я с разметкой делаю не так, и как мне сделать так, что бы и экран не уползал с полного экрана и разметка во фрагментах сдвигалась нормально при появлении клавиатуры?

Вот разметка одного из фрагментов

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back_dkgray"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox_use_screensaver"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:theme="@style/MyCheckBox"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="@string/setting149" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox_use_screensaver_time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:theme="@style/MyCheckBox"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="@string/setting170" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/MyAwesomeStyle"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="@string/setting153" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_time_delay_screen"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:hint="6"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hint" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/hide"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/down_klav" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox_use_screensaver_light"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:theme="@style/MyCheckBox"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="@string/setting154" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox_show_weather"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:theme="@style/MyCheckBox"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="@string/setting114" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Судя по разметке, кнопка должна пролистываться вместе со всем остальным содержимым (это желаемое поведение)? Я нашёл [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22425324). Он советует оставить значение `windowSoftInputMode` по умолчанию и вынести ту часть, которая должна быть прижата к низу видимой части непосредственно в `RelativeLayout`, установив `alignParentBottom` равным `true`.